# Jython in Java error: ImportError: No module named type_check

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, jython

I've read a lot about this matter but nothing seems to work with me. I'm using Netbeans 8.0 on my mac os x 10.9.3
I want to use python code (NLTK tagging code) into my java code using jython.

I use jython-standalone-2.7-b2.jar added to the Libraries at the project properties

When I call a simple print Python code from my Java code it works. But when I add an nltk POS code (which work very fine in Python interpreter) it throws an error.

I tried appending this path at the start of my Python code: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python /Library/Python/2.7/site-package

then the 'import nltk' worked but another error came: ImportError: No module named type_check

How can I get my code work?

Comment: NLTK doesn't support Jython, AFAIK.

Comment: Hi @larsmans do you mean the code will never work?

Comment: It might, but you may have to modify NLTK. Note that Python 2.6 is required for NLTK, Jython stable is at 2.5 and Jython 2.7 is still in beta, so be prepared to patch things up and communicate with the developers of both.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply! but it doesn't work even when I  tried adding jython2.5.4rc1 to the code.

Comment: Obviously, since that doesn't implement the Python 2.6 language.

Comment: I see, I think I should find an alternative for NLTK tagging like the stanford NLP. Thanks a gain

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is due to the fact that when you use jython a new directory site-packages is created : jython_install_path/lib/site-packages

Try to install NLTK so that the module is present in the directory jython_install_path/lib/site-packages. To achieve this, use ez_setup.py (http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py) and easy_install. And then import this directory site-packages to your code.